# Get different Uber driver

Tags: uber

The other day I requested an Uber ride and was matched with a driver **whose rating I didn't like**, so I cancelled the ride. It was very early in the morning (not busy), so when I requested another ride, he was still the closest in-service driver.

Other than calling or texting him directly and asking him not to accept again, does anyone know of a way to not get him again **in that moment**? Uber can prevent future matches through contacting support, but I didn't exactly have time for that and needed a ride.

---

**Update:**

Not really part of the question, more of a musing based off **Johns-305**'s answer. . . The potential for me to open the Lyft app and request a ride (hoping this same driver doesn't drive for both) is so great that it seems Uber should *want* me to be able to find a different driver right away to stay on their network.

Comment: No, there is no way to do this.

Comment: ["Comments are not recommended for any of the following:

Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: @AakashM Comments are the best way to provide Answers that may provoke unwarranted or wrong Downvotes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel, it is about the use of a specific ride sharing service which anybody could use anywhere.

Comment: @Johns-305 No. Comments are not for providing any answers at all. If an answer is receiving "unwarranted downvotes", it should be explained better. If it is receiving "wrong downvotes", it should be better sourced so that people can see that the answer really is correct.

Comment: @GregHewgill How is that not about travel? We accept questions about train tickets, so why not about taxi "tickets"? (And let's not pretend that Uber is anything other than a taxi. Nobody is "sharing a ride" with anybody: your driver had no interest whatsoever in going to your destination until it became clear that somebody was willing to "share the ride" for money, or "pay a fare" as we say in English.)

Comment: This is 100% about Travel and is a pretty good question.  @DavidRicherby Sorry, I've had very well explained and 100% correct Answers get Downvotes because people either don't like the reality of the Answer or refuse to accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  Some ways are guaranteed, others greatly influence the change of getting a different Driver.

You options are:

1. Request a different type of Uber, such as Uber XL or Uber Lux.  You should already know the vehicle type of the driver you're trying to avoid.
2. Request an Uber Pool and hope that particular driver avoids Pools.
3. Wait.

Comment: Option 1 is pretty clever, even though it will obviously cost more, close to double. "Yes, but not directly" seems more like "No, but you have some workarounds." :(